# "No bootable device…” after unplanned empty battery shutdown

Tags: bootcamp, startup, battery, shutdown

The MacBook Pro has suddenly shutdown **(battery went out)** while I am doing Boot Camp to Windows besides macOS.

Now there's a big black and white message "No bootable device..."

I can't do anything, I don't know how to change to macOS I tried:

1. holding <kbd>shift</kbd>
2. and tried <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> but no hope, also tried <kbd>d</kbd> for
3. <kbd>d</kbd> diagnose but still no hope.

What can I do please to fix the problem?

Comment: holding Opt [alt] at boot should show you all available boot drives. The 'no bootable device' message is most likely to be the windows failed install. If you're lucky, the Mac partition should be OK, but you'll probably have to do Boot Camp over from scratch.

Comment: You just saved my life @Tetsujin! I opened macOS and writing this message from there ❤️

Comment: Excellent! Let me drop that in as a quick answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding Opt [alt] at boot should show you all available boot drives.

The "No bootable device..." message is most likely to be the windows failed install.
If you're lucky, the Mac partition should be OK, but you'll probably have to do Boot Camp over from scratch.